# Scope of variables error

Tags: c#, variables, scope

I'm pretty much new to C# programming.

I found this weird scope error in my program, my program won't run. It said below (at lbl[tx].BackColor = Color.DarkViolet;) that "Used of unassigned local variable". But I already declared variable tx inside in my method.

How to fix this? Any help is pretty much appreciated.

```
        async void ShellSort()
    {
        int n = num.Length;
        int gap = n / 2;
        int temp;
        int tx; /// Already declared tx here

        while (gap > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i + gap < n; i++)
            {

                int j = i + gap;
                temp = int.Parse(lbl[j].Text);


                while (j - gap >= 0 && temp < int.Parse(lbl[j - gap].Text))
                {
                    lbl[j-gap].BackColor = Color.Blue;
                    lbl[j].BackColor = Color.Blue;

                    await Task.Delay(time1);
                    lbl[j].Text = lbl[j - gap].Text;
                    tx = j;
                    j = j - gap; 
                }
                lbl[j].Text = temp.ToString();
                lbl[j].BackColor = Color.DarkViolet;
                lbl[tx].BackColor = Color.DarkViolet; /// When I used
                /// it here it wont work.
            }

            gap = gap / 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side note: `async void` is a famously bad idea.  Use `async Task` so the operation can be awaited, observed, etc. by calling code.

Comment: You declared it but never assigned it as the message states: *"Used of **unassigned** local variable"*. For example, if you don't enter the while loop then `tx` was never assigned a value.

Comment: you have to initialize tx

Comment: What if the internal loop is not taken? The compiler cannot discover this situation without running your program. So it tells you that your use of the variable _tx_ outside the internal loop is wrong. Just set the variable tx to zero when you declare it _int tx = 0;_

Comment: I see. It's a logic error. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You *declare* the variable, but don't *assign* anything to it:

```
int tx;
```

You *might* assign to it in your loop:

```
while (j - gap >= 0 && temp < int.Parse(lbl[j - gap].Text))
{
    //...
    tx = j;
    //...
}
// use tx here
```

*But*, what happens if that loop condition starts out as `false`?  If the loop is never entered, no value is ever assigned.  The compiler can't risk that.  Though you *might* assign it a value, the compiler needs to ensure that you *do* assign it a value.

You can do this by simply assigning it a default value:

```
int tx = 0;
```

Integers default to `0` anyway when it comes to properties and whatnot.  So one may as well do the same with local variables.

Answer (score 0):

If body of your `while` will be never executed, `tx` will be unassigned. Compiler just tells you that you need initial value for this case.

So instead of

```
int tx;
```

write

```
int tx = 0; // or what is the correct value for you
```